# Unable to extract csv file from mat file in octave

Tags: octave, octave-gui

[I need help to extract this particular file marked with an arrow in a csv format in the original structure, please help me out with proper line of codes.
Thank You.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok2kp.png)

Comment: That's not a file.  That's an Octave variable.  How do you expect to store a 4 dimensional matrix into a CSV file?  The file is going to be 4GB.

Comment: could you please recommend any other way to extract it. So that i can use the data for an analysis?

Comment: Analysis using what?  Octave has the ability to export variables to file, but it depends on what you're doing to use to analyze it.

Comment: depends on the data it has actually. Probably going to analyze using R, Python or Stata. either of the one

Answer (score 1):

Octave has a `save` command that can save a matrix in a number of different formats.  You can try a binary format, or R and Python can read HDF5 files.

https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/Simple-File-I_002fO.html